# Issue with two iOS Distribution Certificates with same name and different private Keys

Tags: ios

We have two iOS Distribution certificates. I´m having some issues with signing because both distribution certificates have the same name.

If I add both certificates and try to sign with one of them I get an error message that says below.

```
Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile “NTT One Dev" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Distribution: NTT LLP".
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 13.2'
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 13.2'
```

I have to remove the newly added certificate from Keychain access to sign the app. This makes signing an application a time consuming task as I have to export/import certificates every time I want build apps.

Does anyone know of a way of changing the name of the Distribution certificate that Apple generates?

Best regards
Naga

Comment: The name of the certificate is based on the company name you entered when the accounts were created, and likely cannot be changed unless for legal reasons - in which case you'd go through Apple to get this done. All I can say would be to either have separate Mac user accounts - one for appstore and one for enterprise, or keep adding/removing the certificates as and when required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contacted Apple support and they refused to change the name to something other than the legal name of the company. I ended up creating a separate user account on my mac to do the signing for the enterprise account.