# 2 iOS developer certificates with same names

Tags: ios, iphone, enterprise, iphone-developer-program

we have a little Problem here and I hope you guys can help me out!

**Situation:**
We are enrolled in Apples Developer Program (for distributing Apps in the App Store). Since last week we're also enrolled in the Enterprise Program (for in-house App distribution).

**Problem:**
We proceeded with the development and building of the Apps. But we didn't knew that we have to use two different developer certificates for the different Programs. We have now 2 certificates with the same name and XCode is producing an error message each time we want to build the app saying "the certificate cannot be assigned exactly".

**Question:**
How do we change the name of one of the developer certificates?

Many thanks for your help in advance!!!

Comment: Each certificate has a different user ID. Are you sure the name is causing you the problem?

Comment: @BaselAbdelaziz That indeed is an issue. The only way around is to deinstall / reinstall the "right" certificate needed for the current build-process as Xcode uses the name to resolve it. There may be ways to automate that step but I have no solution available.

Comment: @Till, can you precise your workaround a little bit? If I deinstall the certificate I still have to change the name at Apple, right?

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/7358520/1149906

Answer (score 2):

You already have default login keychain So you can add one certificate in login keychain. And then create **new saperate keychain with different name and add your second certificate** to that keychain. Now in your Xcode target setting find keychain certificate path to be used for target and choose appropriate keychain path.

e.g. For one certificate path ........./login/.....

For another certificate change path to ......../mynewkeychain/......

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain, as I have been in the same situation before. You can't easily change the certificates' names. Apple usually does not allow that. [Dhawal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20924073/1329214) is correct, in that you will have to put your certificates into different keychains.

If you want to script your build process, you have to unlock and lock the appropriate keychains `security unlock-keychain` before you call `xcodebuild`. So that only the one certificate you want to sign with is accessible.

There are two very good projects that make managing the keychains and building a lot easier:

- [Openbakery's Gradle Xcode Plugin](http://openbakery.org/gradle.html)
- [rayh's xcoder](https://github.com/rayh/xcoder) for use with rake

Comment: Whenever I create a certificate, the name of the certificate in developer.apple.com is same i.e the company name. How can I add a string suffix to that?