# Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile ***** doesn't include signing certificate ****

Tags: ios, macos, keychain

I had two projects A and B with two distribution certificate with same name ("iPhone Distribution: NTT Check") but different private keys.

Project A is working fine and can able to generate the Archive and IPA successfully using Distribution certificate called "iPhone Distribution: NTT Check".

I added new distribution certificate B to Key chain then project A is getting failed due to new distribution certificate "iPhone Distribution: NTT Check". Both project has same distribution certificate name but different private keys.

Check dependencies
Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile "*****" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Distribution: NTT Check".
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 13.2'
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 13.2'

I am to sure how to fix this error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to have different private keys (and evidently certificates) for each individual project. Try dropping one of them and edit the other's Provisioning Profile to use the same signing certificate.

Comment: @gcharita Thanks for your reply. Can you help me understand why project B is working fine with two distribution certificates in login.keychain and why project A is getting failed due to newly added distribution certificate for Project B.

Comment: That caused due to same name conflicting. It's a common problem in Xcode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202790/2-ios-developer-certificates-with-same-names

Comment: @gcharita excuse for my ignorance if it sounds dumb. Even though the distribution certificate name is same "iPhone Distribution: NTT Check" the private key is different. My question is why project B is working fine with no issues even with two "distribution certificates" in login.keychain.

Comment: @gcharita issued resolved after following your advice to remove the duplicate certificate and editing the provisioning profile accordingly to use the correct certificate.

Comment: So, when Xcode is looking for a valid certificate with this name, apparently, picks the one that created last. (or maybe the last imported in the Keychain) That's why your B project is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode appears to have issues when [2 certificates have the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202790/2-ios-developer-certificates-with-same-names).

Apparently is looking for a valid certificate based on the name and picks the one that created last. (or maybe the last imported in the Keychain) That's why your B project is working fine while project A doesn't.

Either way, you don't need to have different private keys (and evidently certificates) for each individual project. Try dropping one of them and edit the other's Provisioning Profile to use the same signing certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Hence the solution should be to remove the duplicate keys and change the provision profiles accordingly.